# What are some recommended iPhone apps for learning German?

Tags: resource-request, german, germanic-languages

I already use Duolingo, but feel as though it's not enough to propel my language skills and learn even more. Are there any  German apps that are more grammar-based than vocab-based in the App Store (preferably free)?

Comment: "Good" is an entirely subjective term. What is good for you may be terrible for another. There are countless iPhone apps for language learning; each one has at least one person (the creator) who would claim they are good. Can you be more specific and objective in what you're looking for? What would make an app "good" for you?

Comment: Did you try Google: http://www.fluentu.com/blog/german/best-apps-for-learning-german/

Comment: Should these apps use a specific base language (e.g. English) or can they also be fully in German? It would be nice if you could add that to your question.